# While loop throwing blank page

Tags: php

I have a system where users can follow other users, and I'm trying to make the posts of followed users appear on the user's feed page. Unfortunately, my code is just throwing a blank page, I think coming from something in the while loop used to display.

The first query is meant to select all profiles followed by the user, `$res['following']`, then to loop through that to get each individual value plugged into the second while loop, which displays all their posts on the page. Something is breaking it though, and my error reporting isn't showing anything.

Any ideas?

**index.php**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$query=$db->prepare("SELECT user FROM users WHERE id=:i");
$query->bindParam(':i',$i);
$query->execute();

$result = $query->fetch();
$u = $result['user'];

$query2=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM followers WHERE id=:id");
$query2->bindParam(':id',$i);
$query2->execute();

while ($res=$query2->fetch()) {
    $q=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid=:uid")
    $q->bindParam(':uid',$res['following']);
    $q->execute();
    while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
        echo $r['message'] . "<br>" . $r['timestamp'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

**core/init.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = new PDO('login data is fine');

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $i = $_SESSION['id'];

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:i");
    $query->bindParam(":i",$i);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetch();

    $ver = $result["activated"];

    if( $ver == 0) {
        echo "Please <a href='activate.php'>verify your account.</a>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Please <a href='login.php'>log in.</a>";
    $guest = True;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `;`

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid=:uid");
```

Comment: Bugger. Sometimes it's just that fresh pair of eyes. Thank you so much!

Comment: Then please accept the answer so that other users can see that this solves your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $r['message'] . "<br>" . $r['timestamp'] . "<br>";
}
```